# About ExpansionPanel and SQFlite

Tags: dart, flutter

Can i make a ExpansionPanel with header and body content from SQFLite database?

this is my code paste.ofcode.org/b8Mns5bSQxqyjX6BwD8DL8 I want to load the header and body from database

Comment: I saw your code. What is the problem you are facing?. Can you be a little more elaborate?

Comment: Well, when i use listview builder to get the data, the ExpansionPanel header and body doesn't show, but when i use for loop without load data from database, the ExpansionPanel header and body show

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ListView.builder` to build the `List`. ListView.builder is meant for building `UI widgets`.

As it is **not attached** to the view (it's hanging in initState), ListView.builder will not have iterated once (you can put a print inside and see).

**Solution is to use normal list**

```
List.generate(data.length, (index) => new ItemKu(
        false,
        data[index]["category"],
        new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new Text('Hello World'),
        )
    ));
```

Comment: i have make it like that, but it show error when i switch to the page ..

'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart'' : Failed assertion: line 215 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) > index': is not true

Comment: Can you update the latest code and put in paste.ofcode